# Get emoticon's (chars) unicode code

Tags: c#

I need to get emoticon's code in format like 1F600 or 128512. It's just a symbol in my string now.

I found that emoticons described in Uniicode encoding, but CharUnicodeInfo.GetNumericValue seems not working.

How can i do this?

Ok

```
var q = CharUnicodeInfo.GetNumericValue(text[0]);
```

where text[0] holds emoticon (in debug view it's just a picture)
returns -1

Comment: "seems not working"? Please read [ask] and post a [mcve] so we can help you.

Comment: Perhaps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoticons_(Unicode_block) has the info you're looking for?

Comment: I need a way to get code by emoji, not emoji by code. But anyway, thank you.

Comment: Then maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20689645/get-emoticon-unicode-from-char-utf-16 is relevant? You should search Stack Overflow for "unicode emoticon". There's a lot of good info there for doing conversions both ways.

Comment: I did quicksearch by "c#" tag, but didn't found eligible answer. You gave me link to answer with android code.

Comment: Sometimes being a programmer involves studying code in languages that you're not familiar with.

Comment: I definetely agree. But i think, that this shouldn't be the first step. My question is pretty basic, so it's more logically to find answers in "native" language:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say

> `text[0]` holds emoticon

This is not true.

`text[0]` holds the first `Char`. A `Char` is a 16 bit code unit, but emoticons don't fit in a 16 bit code unit. They are represented by two combining characters.

The first combining character is not a valid codepoint in itself, so trying to get the codepoint value returns -1; an invalid code point.

So how do you get the codepoint?

[Return code point of characters in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894021/return-code-point-of-characters-in-c-sharp) explains how you can get a list of all codepoints.

If you only want to get the first codepoint, you can use `Char.ConvertToUtf32` directly:

```
int codepoint = Char.ConvertToUtf32(text, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got to read more about these code points, however. Converting to utf32 worked perfect. Thanks, again.

Comment: @Occam'schainsaw: Start here: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 0):

The reason [CharUnicodeInfo.GetNumericValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56at3k0x(v=vs.110).aspx) returns -1 for you is because the character you're passing *is not a numeric character.* You need to read the documentation.

The Unicode value of an emoticon character in that block is a 32-bit value. For example, 0x1F600. So it will be a 32-bit value made up of the two 16-bit values. So if your string contains that emoticon character, the string will be length 2, and the two `char` values will be 0x0001 and 0xF600. Cast the `char` values to `short` and view them as hex. For example:

```
short c1 = (short)text[0];
short c2 = (short)text[1];
```

In the debugger, view `c1` and `c2` as hex.

Comment: First emoji displayed in text variable is &#128511;. After running your code c1 = -10179, c2 = -8705 :С

Comment: @Occam'schainsaw: You didn't display the hex value, as I said. The decimal number 128511 works out to 0x0001F5FF.

Comment: The decimal number 128511 works out to 0x0001F5FF. I agree. But i got negative numbers not even near with 128511. Or i misunderstanding something?